# Google map not printing properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm having some trouble with printing a Google Map through the JavaScript API V3. The problem is that the Map is displayed in two parts and the top and bottom part of the map are partly overlaying each other.

The code looks like this:

```
  var geocoder;
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: latlng,
      scrollwheel: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
    codeAddress();             
  }


  function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });      
  }
```

Can anyone say what's wrong?

Comment: What does your map_canvas div look like?  And alo please post "#address"

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: <cfoutput>
     <input id="address" type="textbox" style="display:none;" value="#listProperty.postcode1##listproperty.postcode2#" >
     <input type="button" value="Geocode" style="display:none;" onclick="codeAddress()">
     <cfif structKeyExists(url,"print") and url.print eq "yes" >
       <div id="map_canvas" style="height:475px; width:475px;"></div>
     <cfelse>
       <div id="map_canvas" style="height:475px; width:700px;"></div> 
     </cfif>     
   </cfoutput>

Comment: Should edit your post above to include these details.  What is postcode1/2?  Any change you can post a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: In browser the map looks fine. The problem is only when I try to print off the map.

Comment: Does it look incorrect in print preview?  It just printed fine for me.

Comment: In print preview the map looks also incorrect

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. I need at least ten reputation to be able to post some images

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works

```
.map{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 410px;
    overflow: visible;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223);
}
```

Html tag inside (div id="map_canvas" class="map")